# BinaryReader and while statement operators

Tags: c#, binaryreader, binary-serialization

This is not my code. I am supposed to figure out what is going on.   The line of the while statement is where I am confused. Is all its trying to say is read until end of file. I don't understand how it would evaluate to some integer for comparison.

```
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(pathToPK, FileMode.Open))
        {
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                int read = 0;

                while ((read = br.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0) //don't understand this line
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }

                sk = new byte[ms.ToArray().Length]; //sk is a byte[]

                ms.ToArray().CopyTo(sk, 0);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Come to think about I don't understand almost the entire bit of code.

Comment: Did you read the docs of BinaryReader.Read method?

Comment: my answer is correcto..

Comment: @Steve I did, but it was only until now that i saw the return portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically its opening a filestream in FileMode.Open to a specified file (pathToPK). With said fileStream it then opens a binary reader to read the raw bytes and creates a new MemoryStream to copy the binaryContent.

Then, it proceeds to read the whole file by chunks of 1024 bytes. Read method of the BinaryReader returns the number of bytes read, so you can read the condition as "while the reader read at least 1 byte (and tried to read as much as 1024)".

In the end it will create a new byte[] to the length of the whole file, based on the memory stream into which it was copied and actually copy the whole content into sk

Comment: Yea I feel really dumb now cause for some reason I was reading the greater than sign as a less than

Answer (score 2):

It is doing `sk = File.ReadAllBytes(pathToPK);` in a very complicated way.

Comment: Are you saying that I could essentially replace this bit of code with yours.

Comment: I might be missing something, but that is what it looks like to me. You can test it by doing `sk1.SequenceEqual(sk2);` (true if they are the same) and fill `sk1` the old way and `sk2` this way.